# Reference signal choice for lock-in amplifier

Tags: amplifier, noise, frequency, signal-to-noise, lock-in-amplifier

How do you choose the reference frequency when using a lock-in amplifier?

I want to measure the amount of lateral deflection of a laser reflected by a surface that will be oscillating very slightly. I'm going to modulate the laser at a set frequency, and send the trigger signal and the signal from a position-sensitive detector to the lock-in amplifier.

At the moment, I'm not sure how quickly the surface will be oscillating, or how much, hence this measurement. My first guess is to choose a reference frequency that is many times the rate that the surface will be oscillating (for instance, 100x), in order to ensure the lock-in detects the variation of the signal, but I don't know how to optimize this for a clean measurement.

Comment: What does the data sheet for the lock-in amplifier tell you?

Comment: @Andyaka  There isn't one as far as I know.  The manufacturer's website has basic specifications but no information about choosing reference frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

Mike Meade's classic book *Lock-in Amplifiers:principles and applications* is freely available from https://www.sites.google.com/site/lockinamplifiers/ or  from https://archive.org/details/Lock-inAmplifiersPrinciplesAndApplications

You need to read this first.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid any known disturbance frequencies and their harmonics and the upper limit frequency. The Lock-in, of course, acts as a very narrow-band filter (if you make it too narrow you'll lose signal, of course).